# Java Recursion Problem

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I had a recursion interview question problem in Java,Need your help on this.

Write a `**Java function**` such that :: Given an array of ints, is it possible to divide the ints into two groups, so that the sum of the two groups is the same, with these constraints: all the values that are multiple of 5 must be in one group, and all the values that are a multiple of 3 (and not a multiple of 5) must be in the other. (No loops needed.)

`split53({1,1}) → true

split53({1, 1, 1}) → false

split53({2, 4, 2}) → true`

PS:This was a Interview Question for hewlett packard

Comment: question is not clear for me...i got this interview question and i dont know how to proceed

Comment: wait until they make you do this problem and fizz buzz together

Comment: the spec sounds quite clear to me, start hacking on it and post your code when you can not get any further.

Comment: It's your interview and if you start handing in other people's answers, your (possible) future employer might think you know more than you actually do.

Comment: @Deepak, if the question is unclear, why not ask for clarification to those who posed the question?

Comment: @Bart Chill off, there's nothing wrong with researching about your interview questions after the interview :) (Which, sometimes, implies asking for direction.) In fact, I would be reluctant to hire a developer who doesn't do so.

Comment: @Nikita, I'm not upset, so I see no reason to chill out. I agree: there's nothing wrong with asking questions *after* the interview. Note that Deepak did not say he **had** an interview, but used the word **have** , which implies he was in the process of answering (or submitting) the answer to the posed question.

Comment: @Bart Hmm, you're right, I missed that peculiar choice of words. Anyway, whatever he was doing is probably over by now.

Comment: @Nikita, yeah, that's probably true.

Comment: @Nikita and @Bart,This was a interview question asked at HP,I posted the question only after i have reached home and did not have any directions on how about it.Kindly excuse me all if i have troubled you for this

Comment: @Deepak, no harm done. I really though you were asking while doing the test.

Comment: http://codingbat.com/prob/p168295

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question can be easily reduced to following: given a set of integers `numbers` and an integer `target`, is it possible to find a subset of `numbers` with sum equal to `target`?
Let me know if transition needs clarification.

It can be solved with [DP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) in `O(numbers.size * target)` time. The idea is following

1. When `numbers.size` is `0`, the only reachable sum is `0`.
2. Suppose we have `numbers == {1, 3}`, in this case sums `{0, 1, 3, 4}` are available. What if we add another element to `numbers`, `4`?  Now, all old sums can still be reached and some new ones too: `{0 + 4, 1 + 4, 3 + 4, 4 + 4}`. Thus, for `numbers == {1, 3, 4}`, available sums are `{0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8}`.
3. In this fashion, adding number by number, you can build the list of reachable sums.

A working example (it doesn't handle negative numbers, but you can easily fix that)

```
boolean splittable(int[] numbers, int target) {
    boolean[] reached = new boolean[target + 1];
    reached[0] = true;

    for (int number : numbers) {
        for (int sum = target - 1; sum >= 0; --sum) {
            if (reached[sum] && sum + number <= target) {
                reached[sum + number] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return reached[target];
}
```

Run it

```
System.out.println(splittable(new int[]{3, 1, 4}, 7)); // => true
System.out.println(splittable(new int[]{3, 1, 4}, 6)); // => false
```

**edit**
I just noticed the "recursion" part of the requirement. Well, DP can be rewritten as recursion with [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), if that's the hard requirement. This would preserve runtime complexity.

**edit 2**
On groups. You have to assign elements divisible by 3 or 5 to respective groups *before* you proceed with the algorithm. Let's say, sum of all elements is `s`, sum of elements divisible by 3 is `s3` and sum of elements divisible by 5 but not 3 is `s5`. In this case, after you assigned those 'special' elements, you have to split the rest that sum in one group is `s/2 - s3` and in another `s/2 - s5`.

Comment: Although not recursive, it is a neat solution.

Comment: @Nikita Thanks for your impeccable reply

Comment: @Nikita,I have a clarification.i dont see 2 groups which contains elements which are only multiples of 3 and other group which are only multiples of 5,though the solution gives the idea of summation.my actual requirement says i need 2 different groups such that one is multiples of 5 and other is multiples of 3 only.Please clarify

Comment: @Deepak I've clarified how to deal with 3's and 5's in the post.

Comment: @Nikita,i would be thankful to you if you could explain in the same code example which you have posted as to how will you accomplish the grouping of `s3` and `s5`.im a bit confused with the `grouping`.

Comment: @Deepak All this in one sentence: assign 3's and 5's to respective groups (use a loop). Where do you find problem?

Comment: @Nikita,can you explain with an example so that it becomes easier.Im newbie to recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Very slow, but working solution:

```
static boolean canSplit(int[] arr, int lvl, int sum1, int sum2) {
        if (arr.length == lvl) {
            if (sum1 == sum2) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (arr[lvl] % 5 == 0) {
            return canSplit(arr, lvl + 1, sum1 + arr[lvl], sum2);
        } else if (arr[lvl] % 3 == 0) {
            return canSplit(arr, lvl + 1, sum1, sum2 + arr[lvl]);
        }
        return canSplit(arr, lvl + 1, sum1 + arr[lvl], sum2) ||
               canSplit(arr, lvl + 1, sum1, sum2 + arr[lvl]);
    }
```

Call the function:

```
canSplit(arr, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the real recursive solution.

```
private boolean split2(int index, int[] nums, int sum1, int sum2) {
  if (index >= nums.length) {
    return sum1 == sum2;
  }

  if (split2(index + 1, nums, sum1 + nums[index], sum2)) {
    return true;
  }
  if (split2(index + 1, nums, sum1, sum2 + nums[index])) {
    return true;
  }

  return false; 
}
```

This code goes through puting every element into one of the group. If in any combination the two groups are equal it returns true. No loops used and in only one function.

Best for all

edit: Your function takes 4 arguments as input whereas the question gets as input only the array. You have to specify that the desired function could be done using yours with the call `split2(0,nums,0,0);`

Comment: This answer is irrelevant. Does not take into account the multiples of 3 and 5 requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Code that would probably get me fired. But will work :D

Entirely recursive, equally deadly.

```
public boolean split53(int[] nums) {
    return split_fn(0, nums, 0, 0, false, false);
}
public boolean split_fn(int start, int[] nums, int left, int right, boolean fiveLeft, boolean chosen) {
    if (start >= nums.length) {
        if (left == right) return true;
        return false;
    }
    if (nums[start] % 5 == 0) {
        if (!chosen) {
            return split_fn(start + 1, nums, left + nums[start], right, true, true) || split_fn(start + 1, nums, left, right + nums[start], false, true);
        } else {
            return split_fn(start + 1, nums, left + ((fiveLeft) ? nums[start] : 0), right + ((!fiveLeft) ? nums[start] : 0), fiveLeft, chosen);
        }

    }

    if (nums[start] % 3 == 0 && nums[start] % 5 != 0) {
        if (!chosen) {
            return split_fn(start + 1, nums, left + nums[start], right, false, true) || split_fn(start + 1, nums, left, right + nums[start], true, true);
        } else {
            return split_fn(start + 1, nums, left + ((!fiveLeft) ? nums[start] : 0), right + ((fiveLeft) ? nums[start] : 0), fiveLeft, chosen);
        }
    }
    //standard case
    return split_fn(start + 1, nums, left + nums[start], right, fiveLeft, chosen) || split_fn(start + 1, nums, left, right + nums[start], fiveLeft, chosen);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how fast or slow the following solution is. But precisely it is a recursive backtracking solution, which uses no loops as mentioned in the question.

**Here is the code snippet:**

```
public boolean split53(int[] nums) {
    int start = 0, firstPart = 0, secondPart = 0;
    if (split(start, nums, firstPart, secondPart)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean split(int start, int[] nums, int firstPart, int secondPart) {
    if (start >= nums.length) {
        return (firstPart == secondPart);
    }
    if ((start + 1) < nums.length
            && (nums[start] % 3 != 0)
            && (nums[start + 1] % 5 != 0)
            && split(start + 2, nums, firstPart + nums[start], secondPart
                    + nums[start + 1])) {
        return true;
    }
    if ((start + 1) < nums.length
            && (nums[start + 1] % 3 != 0)
            && (nums[start] % 5 != 0)
            && split(start + 2, nums, firstPart + nums[start + 1],
                    secondPart + nums[start])) {
        return true;
    }
    if ((nums[start] % 3 != 0)
            && split(start + 1, nums, firstPart + nums[start], secondPart)) {
        return true;
    }
    if ((nums[start] % 5 != 0)
            && split(start + 1, nums, firstPart, secondPart + nums[start])) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Hope it helps.