# Recursion, split int[] into two groups under restriction

Tags: java, recursion

This question about the same algorithm has already been asked before, and I found the solution I was looking for. Yet, I was wondering how I could've fixed my own solution to solve the following problem:

> Given an array of ints, is it possible to divide the ints into two groups, so that the sum of the two groups is the same, with these constraints: all the values that are multiple of 5 must be in one group, and all the values that are a multiple of 3 (and not a multiple of 5) must be in the other.

The solution I came up with looks like this:

```
public boolean split53(int[] nums) {
  return isPossible(nums,0,0,0);
}
public boolean isPossible(int[] nums,int start,int sum3,int sum5) {
  if(start>=nums.length) return sum3==sum5;
  int tmp=nums[start];

  if(isPossible(nums,start+1,sum3+tmp,sum5)) return true;
  if(isPossible(nums,start+1,sum3,sum5+tmp)) return true;

  if(nums[start]%5==0) {
    sum5+=nums[start];
    tmp=nums[start++];
  }
  else if(nums[start]%3==0) {
    sum3+=nums[start]; 
    tmp=nums[start++];
  }  
  if(start>=nums.length) return sum3==sum5;

  return false;
}
```

It works just fine for most cases, but somehow it doesn't work for nums={3,5,8}. I've already tried to track the data flow, but at some point I'm going wrong.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try to debug? {3,5,8} is quite simple dataset

Comment: it is hard to explain why it is wrong... but, you should split the problem in two parts. case 1... tmp is divided by 3 or 5... case 2... tmp is anything else. You are almost there.

Comment: um, you cant divide this into 2 groups with the given constrains because 8 is neither a multiple of 5 nor of 3...? is the question right?

Comment: in addition: why do you add the nums up to 2 times on the sums, dependable if they are multiples of 3 or 5? i.e. why is a 5 added 2 times and an 8 just once?

Comment: 8 could be in any group ... 3 group or 5 group. (backtracking method should be used).

Comment: i'm working on the solution on codingbat.com, no debugging option there.

Comment: thanks to rdllopes for the hint!

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460564/java-recursion-problem?rq=1

Comment: Yes, that's why I wrote this algorithm has been discussed before. My problem was how to fix my own solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sleeping it over I came up with the following working solution:

```
public boolean split53(int[] nums) {
  return isPossible(nums,0,0,0); 
}
public boolean isPossible(int[] nums,int start,int sum3,int sum5) {
  if(start>=nums.length) return sum3==sum5;
  int tmp=nums[start];

  if(tmp%5==0 || tmp%3==0) {
    if(nums[start]%5==0) {
      if(isPossible(nums,start+1,sum3,sum5+tmp)) return true;
    }
    else if(nums[start]%3==0) {
      if(isPossible(nums,start+1,sum3+tmp,sum5)) return true;
    }  
  } else {
    if(isPossible(nums,start+1,sum3+tmp,sum5)) return true;
    if(isPossible(nums,start+1,sum3,sum5+tmp)) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

I think there must be a way to avoid the duplicate lines of code, but I'm happy as long as it's working.